# Removing Taint from kubernete nodes doesnot work

Tags: 18.04, juju, kubernetes

Ubuntu 18.04

Kubernete on JUJU 


I tried to remove the taint form nodes:

 `kubectl get nodes -o json | jq .items[].spec.taints
[
  {
    "effect": "NoSchedule",
    "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
    "timeAdded": "2019-06-12T20:38:52Z"
  }
]
[
  {
    "effect": "NoSchedule",
    "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
    "timeAdded": "2019-06-12T20:38:57Z"
  }
]
[
  {
    "effect": "NoSchedule",
    "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
    "timeAdded": "2019-06-12T20:39:00Z"
  }
]`

`with this command:`

`kubectl patch node  juju-06819a-0-lxd-70 -p '{"spec":{"taints":[]}}'`


`node/juju-06819a-0-lxd-70 patched
rastin@cloudrnd1:~/.kube$ kubectl patch node  juju-06819a-0-lxd-71 -p '{"spec":{"taints":[]}}'
node/juju-06819a-0-lxd-71 patched
rastin@cloudrnd1:~/.kube$ kubectl patch node  juju-06819a-0-lxd-72 -p '{"spec":{"taints":[]}}'
node/juju-06819a-0-lxd-72 patched`

Nothing happened all the taint still there!

Comment: Have you resolved the root cause of the taint? If the node is still unreachable then the controller will just relabel the node with the taint after you try to patch it.

Comment: It seems there is problem with container storage, I 'll put the solution on answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here with little bit of change:

https://github.com/charmed-kubernetes/bundle/wiki/Deploying-on-LXD#the-profile

On the machine which I have the LXDs I changed the profile to use 'dir' :

`name: juju-##MODEL##
config:
  boot.autostart: "true"
  linux.kernel_modules: ip_tables,ip6_tables,netlink_diag,nf_nat,overlay
  raw.lxc: |
    lxc.apparmor.profile=unconfined
    lxc.mount.auto=proc:rw sys:rw
    lxc.cap.drop=
  security.nesting: "true"
  security.privileged: "true"
description: ""
devices:
  aadisable:
    path: /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize
    source: /dev/null
    type: disk
  aadisable1:
    path: /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled
    source: /dev/null
    type: disk`

Then I applied this profile to my LXC:

`sudo lxc profile assign <container-name> default
Profiles default applied to <container-name>`

You can get 'container-name' by running : $lxc list

Then I restarted all containers:

`$sudo lxc restart --all`

Now all nodes are ready :

`$kubectl get nodes
NAME                   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
container#1   Ready    <none>   6d    v1.14.2
container#2   Ready    <none>   6d    v1.14.2
container#3   Ready    <none>   3d    v1.14.2`